# Problem with apache on linux

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu

I have problem installing apache on ubuntu 8.04. Here's what I got:

```
one@one-desktop:~/Desktop/httpd-2.2.10$ ls
ABOUT_APACHE      buildconf      configure.in  InstallBin.dsp  NOTICE            srclib
acinclude.m4      CHANGES        docs          LAYOUT          NWGNUmakefile     support
Apache.dsw        confdefs.h     emacs-style   libhttpd.dsp    os                test
apachenw.mcp.zip  config.layout  httpd.dsp     LICENSE         README            VERSIONING
build             config.log     httpd.spec    Makefile.in     README.platforms
BuildAll.dsp      config.nice    include       Makefile.win    ROADMAP
BuildBin.dsp      configure      INSTALL       modules         server
one@one-desktop:~/Desktop/httpd-2.2.10$ ./configure
checking for chosen layout... Apache
checking for working mkdir -p... yes
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnulibc1
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnulibc1
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnulibc1

Configuring Apache Portable Runtime library ...

checking for APR... reconfig
configuring package in srclib/apr now
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnulibc1
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnulibc1
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnulibc1
Configuring APR library
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnulibc1
checking for working mkdir -p... yes
APR Version: 1.3.3
checking for chosen layout... apr
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
configure failed for srclib/apr
one@one-desktop:~/Desktop/httpd-2.2.10$ ]
```

What is this ***configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables*** all about? And how to settle the problem?

Comment: Voting to close as 'belongs on Serverfault.' But may I *also* take this opportunity to welcome you to Stackoverflow! =)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing some libraries. try: 
`sudo apt-get install libc6-dev g++ gcc`

Also is there a reason you don't want to install vi apt?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do sudo apt-get install build-essential which will get essential things to build software, which include gcc and g++.